# Clicking a button with a conditional Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm a beginner, learning selenium packpage using python language.

How could I click on the button with the text: ***"Co-assinar"*** only when there is the text: ***'Segue a certidão..."***

I'll put an image below the part of the code I'm talking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jV64.png

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to "collect" the two elements you'd like as variables and then use an `if` statement to check and see if the elements text is equal to "Segue a..." and in that case click.

Something like this:

```py
#Get the button you want to click
button_to_click = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'menor link_amissao_assinar...')

#Get the element that holds the text you're checking
text_you_want = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'texto_original').children[2].text

#If element text equals 'Segue a...' click
if text_you_want == 'Segue a...':
    button_to_click.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p[contains(text(),'Segue a certidão')]")
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[./i[text()=' Co assinar ']]").click()
except:
   pass
```

You can check for the second element and then click the first element if it's there. Handling any exceptions you may want to in case.